# Why is it that the truncate function on the "fs" module only works with integers

Tags: node.js

The truncate function gives a range error whenever a float is supplied on the length argument and forces me to parse an integer. This is not precise enough when I want to get a fraction of the file size.

```
fs.truncate(filePath, stats.size/2,(err)=>{
  if(err) throw err
})
```

> RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "len" is out of range. It
>   must be an integer. Received 513.5
>       at Object.truncate (fs.js:613:3)

This forces me to use

```
fs.truncate(filePath, parseInt(stats.size/2),(err)=>{
  if(err) throw err
})
```

Comment: How do you store a fraction of a byte on disk? What is 1/16 of the character "z"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it that the truncate function on the “fs” module only works with integers

Because a file length is specified in integers only.  There's no such thing as a fractional number of bytes in a file length.  You can't have a file that is 2.5 bytes long.

If you don't pass an integer, then the meaning of what you're trying to do is unclear.  Since the file can only be whole integers, do you want your decimal value to be rounded up, rounded down?  It's unclear.  So, you have to specify exactly what you want.

FYI, `parseInt()` is not really the right function to use.   You should use either `Math.round()`, `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()` depending upon what behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks. My objective is to truncate a file to half its size. From your answer, it seems there is no way to be precise

Comment: @GeofreyAsiimwe - You can't have a file with a half byte length so if the file is an odd length, then you can't cut the file in exactly half.